# Is the CPS a data controller for its defendants?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, data-protection

Alice was charged with an offence by the CPS. Is her file with the subject to the DPA 2018?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

[Privacy Notice - Crown Prosecution Service (CPS)](https://www.cps.gov.uk/privacy-notice-crown-prosecution-service-cps)

> ... The CPS is the data controller for all data referred to below.
> ...
>
> ... In general, personal data is held by the CPS about defendants,
> victims / witnesses and others involved in the Criminal Justice System
> within criminal case files. ...

(Found with a web search for "Is the CPS a data controller for its defendants?" - first result.)